# ROS Answers SE migration: 3D point cloud

Tags: laser, transform-listener, tf2, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pcl_assembler_client.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from laser_assembler.srv import AssembleScans2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

rospy.init_node("assemble_scans_to_cloud")
rospy.wait_for_service("assemble_scans2")
assemble_scans=rospy.ServiceProxy('assemble_scans2',AssembleScans2)
pub=rospy.Publisher("/point_Cloud",PointCloud2,queue_size=2)
r=rospy.Rate(10)
while True:
        try:
                resp=assemble_scans(rospy.Time(0,0),rospy.get_rostime())
                print "Got cloud with %u points" % len(resp.cloud.data)
                pub.publish(resp.cloud)
        except rospy.ServiceException, e:
                print "service call failed: %s" %e
        r.sleep()
```

scan_to_pcl.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2 as pc2
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from laser_geometry import LaserProjection

class Laser2PC():
        def __init__(self):
                self.laserProj=LaserProjection()
                self.pcPub=rospy.Publisher("/laserPointCloud",pc2,queue_size=1)
                self.laserSub=rospy.Subscriber("/scan",LaserScan,self.laserCallback)

        def laserCallback(self,data):
                cloud_out=self.laserProj.projectLaser(data)
                self.pcPub.publish(cloud_out)
if __name__=='__main__':
        rospy.init_node("scan_to_pcl")
        l2pc=Laser2PC()
        rospy.spin()
```

my launch file is,

```
<launch>

<node name="scan_to_pcl" pkg="cloud_data" type="scan_to_pcl.py"/>

<node type="point_cloud2_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler"  name="pcl_assembler_server">
<remap from="cloud" to="laserPointCloud"/>
<param name="max_clouds" type="int" value="400" />
<param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
</node>


<node name="pcl_assembler_client" pkg="cloud_data" type="pcl_assembler_client.py" output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

These is code i'm using to generate point cloud data using the laser_assembler package but it is not extruded along the third axis i.e it is not 3D. Can someone help me out on how to achieve 3D cloud.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269229/3d-point-cloud/) by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-24**:
Are you asking someone to translate it from C++ to Python for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's already a Python class that does that:

https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_geometry/blob/indigo-devel/src/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.py

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thank you for the reply I used laser_assembler to transform laser scan data to point cloud but it is not 3D(I want to extrude it along the z axis).Can you help me with this.
I used projectlaser() function but it didnt give me 3D point cloud

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
How did you try it? Please update your question with your attempts and that you need this to be 3D as that isn't stated in the question.

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2017-08-28**:
I have used projectlaser() function but i didn't get 3D cloud.I'm getting data published on pointcloud2 and i can also view it in rviz but not 3D cloud

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Please update your question with *how* you attempted to use it (i.e., code).

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2017-08-30**:
i have uploaded the code #jayess

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-09-08**:
Did you solve this problem?

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2017-09-08**:
Yeah the problem is solved